# Python: Programming 8051

Tags: python, microcontroller, low-level, 8051

Can I program 8051 using Python?

I'm not getting any of the to program 8051 in python environment.

If anybody knows, please help me.

Comment: Is it just me or does this question make no sense? Python is a high-level interpreted language. The microcontroller only understands its instruction set. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Oddly enough, the latest swanky i7's also only understand their instruction set.

Comment: @Jay: Of course. What's the intent of your comment?

Comment: Why python? C is used for this kind of stuff (or even ASM).

Comment: @delnan remember the x86 processor or arm or any other is just an instruction set as well.  Not an unreasonable question, starting to be more common, not the first time this has been discussed on SO, not for the 8051 in particular but alternate languages has been discussed.

Answer (score 6):

There is [Python-on-a-Chip](https://code.google.com/archive/p/python-on-a-chip/), but note its "disclaimer":

> "The PyMite VM DOES NOT HAVE:
>
> - A built-in compiler
> - Any of Python's libraries (no batteries included)
> - A ready-to-go solution for the beginner (you need to know C and how to work with microcontrollers)"

Thus, if the questioner's goal for python was to avoid dealing with the strangeness of the 8051, this may not help.

In particular, the 8051 is a "Harvard" style architecture, with separate RAM and ROM codespaces, and with very limited internal RAM, and larger external RAM that can be accessed only via loading the special DPTR register and then reading or writing indirectly, plus there's no external RAM stack support, nor intrinsic support for stack-based variables. Thus, most "general purpose" high-level languages need lots of customization and reworking to run on the 8051.

A good 8051-specific C-compiler can hide many of these low-level details, but you wind up burning lots of cycles to do things that are single instructions on desktop CPUs and even on most newer embedded controller architectures, and even if you can live with that level of in-efficiency, you still need to sort out the various memory spaces and other specifics.

So, getting Python to work on the 8051 is likely to be a challenging project for someone deeply familiar with its quirky architecture. If your goal is to dump a python onto the 8051 to avoid needing to learn these quirks, I'm not sure that is possible. (But, I suppose the C compilers keep getting better and better...)

Answer (score 4):

[Python-on-a-Chip](http://code.google.com/p/python-on-a-chip/) looks about as close as you're going to get. It can run on some things that are just a bit beefier than the 8051.

Comment: Nice! I hadn't seen that before.